# Overlapping scrollviews

Tags: android, scrollview, overlapping

I have a problem... I have two scrollviews in a absolutelayout. in other words they are fullscreen and laying over each other

the top scrollview is a horizontal scrolling one and the bottom one is a vertical scrolling scrollview.

when I scroll horizontal I want the top one to scroll and when I scroll vertical I want the bottom one to scroll.

but my problem is that the horizontal scrollview takes all scroll events so the bottom one never receives a scroll event...

How can I resolve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Also I noticed your use of an AbsoluteLayout, which is deprecated. Mainly due to the fact that screen sizes and resolutions are all different now. It probably looks great on your emulator or phone, but try putting it on a tablet, or some other phone (nothing will look right). Just a heads up.

Comment: I use fill_parent so the scrollviews will always be full size :)

Answer (score 1):

How about nesting them? You can make it look visually the same, via paddings and margins and furthermore you can control which view handles the touches.

I am not sure if you can say that one scroll view should handle only horizontal and the other to handle only vertical - probably not. But you can override onTouchEvent and onInterceptTouchEvent in both to define whatever behaviour you need! (Check out http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.html )

For example, if you want the parent scroll view to handle only vertical scroll, and the child the handle horizontal, you should

```
-override onInterceptTouchEvent(Event e) {
      if (e.getAction() == ACTION_DOWN){
        //dispatch the call manually to the scroll view below you 
        mChild.onTouchEvent(e);
        super.onTouchEvent(e);
      }
      if (e.getAction() == ACTION_MOVE && the move is horizontal){
         mChild.onTouchEvent(e);
      } else {
         super.onTouchEvent(e); 
     }
      return true;
}
```

}

Or something like that. It is not exaclty what you should do, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably need to implement a custom control for this. You'll need a [Scroller](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Scroller.html) class for your custom control. Also you can download [source code for ScrollView class](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/widget/ScrollView.java) and modify it to be bidirectional.

And don't put scrollable things into other scrollable things - they tend to fight over touch events.

Comment: But in what way would that help? the underlying view will never get the touch events if something else is taking it before?